# Migration from v6 to v7

Tags: react-hook-form

I have upgraded to v7 of react-hook-form today. And all went fine until i came across some legacy code using ref attribute.

In version 6 this worked perfectly

```js
<ToggleSwitch toggleName='ifMonitoring'
              ref={(e) => {
                 monitoring.current = e;
                 register(e);
                 }}
                />
```

But in version 7 ref is not used anymore, instead its `{...register('ifMonitoring')}`. This works fine accross the application but the above example is only one which doesnt work.

I have tried to search for similar issues but to no avail.

Anyone can help?

EDIT:

Adding more code to better understand this

```js
function Edit() => {

const monitoring = useRef(null);

return <Controller name='monitoring' control={control} render={({ field: { ref }, fieldState }) => <ToggleSwitch ref={ref} checked={portInfo.isMonitored} />} />
```

ToggleSwitch is component with its own state. It does have onChange but to maintain its state

```js
const ToggleSwitch = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const [toggleCheck, setToggleCheck] = useState(props.checked);

  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    setToggleCheck((prevState) => !prevState);
    if (props.onChange) {
      props.onChange(props.entry._id);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`toggle btn btn-sm`}>
      <input type='checkbox' defaultChecked={toggleCheck} onChange={handleOnChange} ref={ref} name={`toggle`} />
      <div className='toggle-group'>
        <label htmlFor={`toggle`} className={`btn btn-success`}>
          In Use
        </label>
        <label htmlFor={`toggle`} className={`btn btn-danger`}>
          Not in Use
        </label>
        <span className={`toggle-handle btn btn-light btn-xs`}></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

EDIT 2&3:

[Not working v7 Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-sea-cxbzw)

[Working v6 Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-microservice-1kvem)

Comment: Does your `ToggleSwitch` component have `onChange` and `value` props? If so, you could wrap the component with `<Controller />` provided by RHF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ref` is actually still there, it's returned by `register` among other things that we spread.

There is [an example on the React Hook Form documentation to share ref usage](https://react-hook-form.com/faqs#Howtosharerefusage).

You can do like this:

```js
const { ref, ...rest } = register("ifMonitoring");
<ToggleSwitch
  {...rest}
  ref={(e) => {
    monitoring.current = e;
    ref(e);
  }}
/>;
```

### Edit

In your specific case, you are passing the `...rest` to your `ToggleSwitch` component, but the component does not forward these props to the inner input (except the name that you pass yourself in a prop).

The problem here comes especially from `onChange` that is part of the elements inside your `rest` variable. As you have also your custom `onChange`, you can combine both yours and the one of React Hook Form.

So, in your main component you can pass the `rest` props like this:

```js
<ToggleSwitch
  inputProps={rest}
  ref={(e) => {
    ref(e);
    inUseRef.current = e;
  }}
  // [...]
/>
```

And in your `ToggleSwitch` component, you can call the `onChange` of RHF in your own function, pass the input props to the input, and pass your `onChange` function after.

```js
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  setToggleCheck((prevState) => !prevState);
  if (inputProps.onChange) {
    inputProps.onChange(e);
  }
};

// [...]

<input
  // [...]
  {...inputProps}
  onChange={handleOnChange}
  ref={ref}
  // [...]
/>
```

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-monad-9w53v).

Comment: Thanks, i have tried this but it doesnt seem the ref is forwarded correctly. I always get value of default.
If i console.log ref in ToggleSwitch i get this:
```
function ref(e)
```
instead of the input

Comment: Hi, i added a codesandbox with all my code. If you hit submit you will get console.log with true or false. However this will always be what is default. At the moment is set to true so it will always print true regardless what toggleswitch ise set to :-( any idea?

Comment: Thanks for the two codesandbox examples, it's much easier to investigate with that :) I've updated the answer.

Comment: Wow. Perfect. Thank you so much, this works like a charm. Well worth half of my reputation :-)